# converting a csv to json/dictionary and grouping on an ID

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have some data, a sample of which is included, that I want to turn into a dictionary in python and/or in json format

You will see that the ID repeats. In other words there is a timestamped value for each ID every 15 minutes

I am trying to create a nested dictionary that would use the ID as the key and datetime/flow pairs as the values for each key

```html
ID      datetime             flow
762972  01/01/2017 00:00    -1
763753  01/01/2017 00:00    6.00E-05
763776  01/01/2017 00:00    -1
769472  01/01/2017 00:00    0.00132
793144  01/01/2017 00:00    0
799864  01/01/2017 00:00    0
812926  01/01/2017 00:00    0.00108
821553  01/01/2017 00:00    0
829800  01/01/2017 00:00    -1
830174  01/01/2017 00:00    0
762972  01/01/2017 00:15    -1
763753  01/01/2017 00:15    6.00E-05
763776  01/01/2017 00:15    -1
769472  01/01/2017 00:15    0.00048
793144  01/01/2017 00:15    0
799864  01/01/2017 00:15    6.00E-05
812926  01/01/2017 00:15    0.00024
821553  01/01/2017 00:15    0.00012
829800  01/01/2017 00:15    -1
830174  01/01/2017 00:15    0
762972  01/01/2017 00:30    -1
763753  01/01/2017 00:30    6.00E-05
763776  01/01/2017 00:30    -1
769472  01/01/2017 00:30    0.0006
793144  01/01/2017 00:30    0
799864  01/01/2017 00:30    0
812926  01/01/2017 00:30    0
821553  01/01/2017 00:30    0
829800  01/01/2017 00:30    -1
830174  01/01/2017 00:30    0
```

I am trying to get to this format I believe where each ID would have each of the datetime/flow records associated with it stored within a nested dictionary

Can anyone offer any advice. I have been trying to sort the original .csv on ID first and then using groupby functions but so far no success

Thanks

```html
nested_dict = { '762972': [{'datetime': '01/01/2017 00:00', 'flow': '-1'}, {'datetime': '01/01/2017      00:15', 'flow': '-1'}, {'datetime': '01/01/2017 00:30', 'flow': '-1'}],  
                '763753': [{'datetime': '01/01/2017 00:00', 'flow': '6.00E-05'}, {'datetime': '01/01/2017 00:15', 'flow': '6.00E-05'}, {'datetime': '01/01/2017 00:30', 'flow': '6.00E-05'}] 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group by ids you can then [Iterate through the groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) and build your dictionary. You can then export your dictionary to json or csv using their respective python modules.

something like:

```py
output = {}
for name, group in df.groupby('ID'):
    try:
        output[name].append(group)
    except KeyError:
        output[name] = [group]
json.dumps(output) # Your json
```

There might be a pandas-only way to do it but i'm not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was going in a similar direction but hadn't solved it. However when I try your solution I get this error  --> 'TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable' which seems to suggest it doesn't like working with dataframes ?